# Flutter : Crash on using "package:http/http.dart" on iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, flutter

I am using the Flutter beta 0.15v with Android Studio.The crash only occurs on iOS simulator - IphoneX 11.2.

```
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'stdout' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: stdout
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
#1      stdout (package:flutter_tools/src/base/io.dart:176)
#2      StdoutLogger.writeToStdOut (package:flutter_tools/src/base/logger.dart:100)
#3      StdoutLogger.printStatus (package:flutter_tools/src/base/logger.dart:95)
#4      _AppRunLogger.printStatus (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/daemon.dart:849)
#5      printStatus (package:flutter_tools/src/globals.dart:39)
#6      ResidentRunner._serviceDisconnected (package:flutter_tools/src/resident_runner.dart:756)
#7      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1122)
#8      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#9      _FutureListener.handleWhenComplete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:151)
#10     _Future._propagateToListeners.handleWhenCompleteCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:603)
#11     _Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:659)
#12     _Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:477)
#13     _Future._asyncComplete.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:507)
#14     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#15     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#16     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:949)
#17     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41)
#18     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50)
#19     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:113)
#20     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:166)
```

API call code as follows that uses http.dart

```
 import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

              _loadData() async {
            String dataURL = "https://api.github.com/orgs/abc/members";
            http.Response response = await http.get(dataURL);
            setState(() {
              final membersJSON = JSON.decode(response.body);

              for (var memberJSON in membersJSON) {
                final member = new Member(
                    memberJSON["login"], memberJSON["avatar_url"]);
                _members.add(member);
              }
            });
          }
```

When you run it on ios simulator, the above exception is thrown everytime.

Member data class

```
class Member {
  final String login;
  final String avatarUrl;

  Member(this.login, this.avatarUrl) {
    if (login == null) {
      throw new ArgumentError("login of Member cannot be null. "
          "Received: '$login'");
    }
    if (avatarUrl == null) {
      throw new ArgumentError("avatarUrl of Member cannot be null. "
          "Received: '$avatarUrl'");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks more like an emulator issue than an http issue.

Comment: I'd try `flutter channel dev` `flutter doctor`. The current `beta` is a bit dated already.

Comment: Tried the dev channel, but no progress till now. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you post your dart code?

Comment: Updated the api calling code. Do check

Comment: Could you past also your Member class code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved after creating the whole demo in a new project again. Probably the issue was with the build process for ios only, as the android counterpart of the old project was executing correctly. Such annoying issue will be resolved in future updates I hope.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried this code and is working fine on my iPhone X with iOS 11.2.

```
_loadData() async {
String dataURL = "https://api.github.com/orgs/raywenderlich/members";
http.Response response = await http.get(dataURL);
setState(() {
  final membersJSON = JSON.decode(response.body);

  for (var memberJSON in membersJSON) {
    final member = new Member(
        memberJSON["login"], memberJSON["avatar_url"]);
   //_members.add(member);
    debugPrint("${member.login}");
  }
});
```

}

The error is in the `dart.io` library used with [HTTPClientRequest](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-io/IOSink-class.html) and the exception is in the line 176 [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flutter/flutter/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/base/io.dart).

I've no error using `http` on my `iOS emulator`. So I guess the problem is in your SDK version or in the data you are parsing. Or there is something wrong with your emulator... Have you tried on a real device?

Here my flutter version:

```
Flutter 0.1.5 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 3ea4d06340 (5 weeks ago) • 2018-02-22 11:12:39 -0800
Engine • revision ead227f118
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759
```

You can try my example project [here](https://github.com/shadowsheep1/flutter_app_000006).

Please try it and let me know if it works or you get the same error.

Moreover type `flutter --version` and paste your output.

Comment: I am referring to the raywenderlich tutorial and the open API is follows : https://api.github.com/orgs/raywenderlich/members. P.S. : The same API is running without issue on Android emulator

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna I’ve you tried my code? Does it give you any exceptions? And again, can you post Member class code?

Comment: By member class, you mean the json structure. If yes then https://api.github.com/orgs/raywenderlich/members is giving the json.

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna Not the json. I mean the dart code part that you generate with some tool (swagger? as you talk about open api). Because maybe in that code you have some log function that on Android works fine while on iOS try to call 'stdout' on some class that doesn't have such method... How did you generate the dart Member class code? Or better could I see it? Anyway I guess that if you run the code without member class you get no error ain't it?

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. Check the Question, added the Member data class.

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna so I still get no error (in fact your member class is quite empty ;) )... https://github.com/shadowsheep1/flutter_app_000006 try it on your own.

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna please try my code and let me know if it works. Moreover paste the output of `flutter --version`. I really have no issue using http in my project with iOS simulator...

Comment: Thanks for the guidance but strangely when I made yet another demo with the same code I posted. It worked perfectly on both ios and android respectively. Probably some issue with the app build for ios.

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna So strange... and if you remove (but keep apart for further investigation) the ios folder in the project you have the issue and rebuild it? Then if it works you can check the differences between them. Anyway I’m happy you get rid of the error with a brand new project.

Comment: @JIteshSUvarna if you’d like to thank with an upvote, it’ll be appreciated ;)